# Rewrite BehaviorSuject that takes either localStorage or Observable in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular-2+, rxjs

I have this code

```
employee = this.identityService.me;
employeeToken: Observable<string> = this.employee.pipe(map((e) => e.token));

currentHead = new BehaviorSubject(localStorage.getItem('head'));
```

What I need to do is to change the `currentHead` if the local storage is empty. So I do this in the ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeToken.subscribe(e => {
        if (!this.currentHead.value || this.currentHead.value === '') {
            this.currentHead.next(e);
        }
    });
}
```

It works, but somehow I feel like this should e feasible with rxjs in the initialization of `currentHead`, no?

Where I failed is, that the local storage is not an observable but `this.employee` is, so I struggle to compare them. I tried some *convert observable to behaviorsubject* but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `ngOnInit()` is the best suitable way for that. Clean and easy to spot. The initialization of the other two variables should also be part of ngOnInit (`employee` and `employeeToken`).

Something like that:

```
employee: Empoyee;
employeeToken: Observable<string>;
currentHead: BehaviorSubject<ADD-TYPE-HERE>;

...

ngOnInit() {
    const headFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('head');
    employee = this.identityService.me;
    employeeToken = this.employee.pipe(map((e) => e.token));
    this.currentHead = new BehaviorSubject(localStorage.getItem('head'));
    
    this.employeeToken.subscribe(e => this.currentHead.next(e));
}
```

Not sure you need this:

```
if (!this.currentHead.value || this.currentHead.value === '') {
```

Because this is a subscription. Every time the empoloyeeToken change, you have to update it, right?